# Is this possible to make full dynamic contact form by JavaScript without PHP?

Tags: forms, dynamic, contacts

Actually I know that the form validation is possible by JavaScript but confused that after validation, is it full dynamic and don't need to be used PHP at all?

Comment: You need an application to handle that form on the server side in order to save the form or send its content by email, etc...

Comment: Is this possible to make the application only via JavaScript?

Comment: You can use [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) to write server side JavaScript.